# Can I use controller in other controller in angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'd like to use Angular JS scrollbar to show content.

Here are two controllers I want to use.

```
module.controller('productsCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.products = [
            {src:'../static/images/image-3.png', title : 'Image 3'},
            {src:'../static/images/image-4.png', title : 'Image 4'},
            {src:'../static/images/image-3.png', title : 'Image 5'},
            {src:'../static/images/image-3.png', title :'Image 5'}
        ];
    });
```

And this is scrollbar controller.

```
module.config(function (ScrollBarsProvider) {
            // scrollbar defaults
            ScrollBarsProvider.defaults = {
                autoHideScrollbar: false,
                setHeight: 200,
                scrollInertia: 200,
                axis: 'yx',
                advanced: {
                    updateOnContentResize: true
                },
                scrollButtons: {
                    scrollAmount: 'auto', // scroll amount when button pressed
                    enable: true // enable scrolling buttons by default
                }
            };
        });

    module.controller('scrollCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.scrollbarConfig = {
            theme: 'dark',
            scrollInertia: 500
        }
    });
```

And here is my html code.

```
<div class='' ng-controller ='scrollCtrl'>
<div class='prducts_thumbnail thumb_container' ng-controller='productsCtrl' ng-scrollbars ng-scrollbars-config="scrollbarConfig">

        <div class='col-md-4' ng-repeat='product in products'>
           <a href='#'><img ng-src = '{{product.src}}' alt="{{product.title}}" /></a>
        </div>

     <div class='clearfix'></div>
```

How can i implement this?

Comment: Did something break?

Comment: It shows error like this.                                                                         Multiple directives [ngControllerngScrollbars, new/isolated scope<div class="prducts_thumbnail" ng-scrollbars="" ng-controller="productsCtrl" ng-scrollbars-config="scrollbarConfig">] asking for {4} on: {5}                          I think this error is on        <div class='prducts_thumbnail'  ng-scrollbars ng-controller='productsCtrl' ng-scrollbars-config="scrollbarConfig"> this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think you could use one controller in another controller.

You could implement what you want as follows.

```
<div class='thumb_container' ng-controller = 'scrollCtrl'>
      <div class='prducts_thumbnail'  ng-scrollbars ng-scrollbars-config="scrollbarConfig">
         <div ng-controller='productsCtrl'>
            <div class='col-md-4' ng-repeat='product in products'>
               <a href='#'><img ng-src = '{{product.src}}' alt="{{product.title}}" /></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class='clearfix'></div>
      </div>
      </div>
```